# How to remove this "Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response URL with MIME type text/html" with chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Extension for mbasic.facebook.com, but it work only in mbasic.facebook.com, and not in facebook.com, I get this MSG in facebook.com when I run the extension:

"Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://mbasic.facebook.com/ with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details."

Works perfert if I'm on mbasic.facebook.com, but not in facebook.com, Is it possible to remove the CORB blocked with a code in the Background.js? How can I fix it?

Thank You

Comment: As shown in the [official documentation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches) (it's in the document linked in the error message) do the request in your background script.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, but what is the code that I should add in the background.js? Thank you.

Comment: It's shown in the documentation.

Comment: I have read the page 3 times, but I can not understand, in the point 4, it says, I need the Allowlisting for this?. Please, could you tell me at what point I find the probable solution. Thank you.

Comment: The example is shown in section 2.

Comment: @wOxxOm , One question, it is actually working if I'm mbasic.facebook.com , I can get the DOM only if i'm in the page, but it does not work if I'm in facebook.com, my question is... Will this still work if i'm on mbasic or anyway I will have to add the code to the background?

Comment: You'll need permissions for the other URL in your manifest.json. Either `"<all_urls>"` or a specific URL pattern.